# How to get file path of content in class library

Tags: c#, class-library

I have an Excel file that has a Build Action of `content` in a class library. The library is referenced by both an ASP.NET WebForms application and a console application, and the Excel file is used by both. Is there a way I can programmatically get the file path of this file?

I know in ASP I can do this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"bin")
```

And in the console app I can do this:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Those work, but I'm wondering if there's better, consolidated way to find the file from the assembly and return the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach works fine in all environments you just should change it so that it does not look for the entry assembly but the specific assembly.

Easiest way to do this is:

```
typeof(Some.Type.From.That.Assembly).Assembly.Location
```

An alternative would be to use embedded resources so that you can load the file directly from the assembly. Of course, this would not work if the file has to be writable by the user.

Comment: An embedded resource won't work very well because we have to do com interop with the excel file (ugh) and need it on disk. I was hoping to avoid doing a `MapPath` or `Path.Combine` into the `bin` directory and finding the file, but there may not be another way...

Comment: You can always save the file from embedded resource into temp directory and then do the interop there. It would also prevent issues if multiple processes touch the file or excel for some reason hangs and does not free the file.